# Which quadrant of two crossing lines does a point fall within

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I have two lines defined by two points each,

```
Line{(x1, y1), (x2, y2)}
```

These lines will never be parallel, nor will either ever be completely horizontal nor vertical. I also have a point *(x, y)*.

I need to be able to mathematically find in which "direction" from the crossing of the two Lines the Point is in. By direction I mean *above, below, right, left*.

I have tried to figure out how to do this, but so far I've had no luck. Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the point of intersection? If yes, then you can compare the coordinates of the point of intersection to those of the given point. There will be four possibilities which correspond to the four possible quadrants the point can lie in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Find the intersection of the two lines, which is always possible since they always intersect. Call that point $(x_c, y_c)$
- Now compare the coordinates of $(x, y)$ w.r.t $(x_c, y_c)$

  - If $x > x_c$ the point is to the right of the intersection
  - If $y > y_c$ the point is above the intersection
  - (...)

Comment: Thanks for the help =)